# Restrict respondent access by setting a password for google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I want to create a survey using Google Froms, but only limited people who have the codes can submit the form and do the survey. I have already created a list of codes inside a Google Sheet. When I try to link the Form and Sheet by using Apps Script, it does not work somehow.

Wonder how should i fix my code? or is there another way or plugins that are useful for setting restrictions of filling the form?

```
function checkCodes(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var response = e.response;
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
  var codeQuestionIndex = 0; 
  var codeQuestion = itemResponses[codeQuestionIndex].getResponse();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('MY_SHEET_LINK');
  var codeSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var codeRange = codeSheet.getRange('A:A'); // all the codes are in the column A
  var codes = codeRange.getValues().flat();

  if (!codes.includes(codeQuestion)) {
    form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. I have 3 questions. 1. What is the relationship between your script and your question? 2. About `I want to create a survey using Google Froms, but only limited people who have the codes can submit the form and do the survey.`, in this case, how will you confirm the match between the users and the codes? 3. Can I ask you about the detail of `When I try to link the Form and Sheet by using Apps Script, it does not work somehow.`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can add a password section to a google form.  Google it.

Comment: @Cooper Sure, I will try that out as well. ty

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for the confusion. 1. The script is written directly in Google Forms 2. I considered making the forms anonymously, so no Google verification is required. Only needs a code to access or submit the form. 3. I am trying to compare the user's first question (e.g. What's the code) response with a Google Sheet that I inserted a list of codes inside. If the response/answer does not match any of the codes inside, the user will fail to submit the form. The problem I have right now is I am not able to reach the goal of my poor skill lool. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to restrict access to Google forms only for specific accounts or based on tokens/correct answers. You can however filter the responses post submission of responses and discard the responses not submitted with a proper access token.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. How can I filter and discard the response?

Comment: @FanKey89 There is inbuilt filtering in Google sheets. You can also use ``=FILTER`` formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script *after* a response has been submitted, but not while a user is entering data in a form. But you do not need a script in the first place. In the Google Forms editor:

1. Insert a short answer question titled `Enter password` as the first thing in the form.
2. Click **More ︙** and choose **Response validation**.
3. Select **Text > Contains >** `shibboleth` (or another password of your choosing).
4. In the **Custom error text** field, enter `Incorrect password.` This is an important step — the default warning message would reveal the correct password, which you do not want.
5. Click **Add section** .

When a user opens the form, they will only see the password prompt, and will need to enter the correct password to proceed past that prompt.

The example above uses the same password for everyone. To assign multiple alternative passwords, use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) in step `3`, like this:

**Regular expression > Matches >** `^(shibboleth|lollapalooza|baldiya|nevada)$`

This regex is case-sensitive.

To require that the user enters a code like `fz4992` that consist of two letters followed by four digits, where the first digit is always `4` and the last is `2`, use this:

**Regular expression > Matches >** `^([A-z][A-z]4\d\d2)$`

This regex is case-insensitive in the sense that it will accept lowercase and uppercase Latin letters in the first two positions.

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation of my questions. The password or the code that I consider giving out is for one-time use only. If I set a response validation, then the answer will be the same for everyone.

Comment: Edited the answer to add an example of using a regular expression.